# How to managment over 100k access for a php file in my vps?

Tags: php, performance, caching, optimization, vagrant

I have a app over 500k member and all of their user get data from server every 1h.
All of my data store in a php file and device get it with JSON.
This is my Simple php file:

```
<?php

$response = array();
header('Content-type: application/json');
$response["AppInf"] = array();
    $product = array();
    $product["apptitle"] = "string1";
    $product["apps"] = "string2";
    $product["apps2"] = "string3";
    $product["apps4"] = "string4";
    $product["idapp"] = "stringid";
     array_push($response["AppInf"], $product);
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

but when access over 15k user in server my cpu load grow to 100%.
I have a good vps server with 64g ram and xenon cpu.
Anyone can help me for manage and fix this problem???

Comment: You're using PHP to generate completely static json files?

Comment: For an HTTP server incoming load rate should be request per second or such. Expressing just '15k user' doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mat yes my file is completely  static.

Comment: @HamidrezaSoleimani how to fix it?

Comment: @MostafaRostami Using standard benchmark tools like Apache Benchmark (ab), you can get standard report like *Concurrency Level*, *Time taken for tests*, *Requests per second*, *Time per request* and such statistics which can be a base for tuning your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If your content is really static as in your example: store content in static file and use caching. If your content is the same for at least a group of users then you only have to calculate the desired result once and store the data for later retrieval
2. Consider using a reverse proxy like `varnish` to move load from your web server to another server
3. If it is possible: Don't let all users fetch data at the same time. Add some random offset to the time when data is being pulled.

Comment: thanks for your response: yes my content  are static how to use cashing?2-I cant move load to another webserver.3-how to add randome offset to the time?